# A simple library using Flask and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy

This is the `main.py` script that does most of the work of Adding movies (`Movie` objects) as well as modifying and removing:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash, url_for, redirect
import sqlite3
from datetime import date
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from movie import Movie

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "LOL"
Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///adatabase.db', connect_args={'check_same_thread': False}, echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Base.metadata.bind = engine
Session = (sessionmaker(bind=engine)) #scoped_session
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session = Session()

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/form', methods = ['POST','GET'])
def form():
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            title = request.form['title']
            release_date = request.form['release_date']
            print(release_date)
            session.add(Movie(title,date(int(release_date.split('-')[0]),int(release_date.split('-')[1]),int(release_date.split('-')[2]))))
            session.commit()
            session.close()
            return redirect(url_for('table'))
    except:
        flash("An error occured while writing to database")
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('form.html', title = "Form")

@app.route('/table')
def table():
    con = sqlite3.connect('adatabase.db')
    con.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('select * from movies')
    movies = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template('table.html',movies = movies, title = "Movies")

@app.route('/delete/<int:post_id>')
def delete(post_id):
    query = session.query(Movie).filter(Movie.id == post_id).first()
    session.delete(query)
    session.commit()
    session.close()
    return redirect(url_for('table'))

@app.route('/modify/<int:post_id>', methods = ['POST','GET'])
def modify(post_id):
    query = session.query(Movie).filter(Movie.id == post_id).first()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.form['title']
        release_date = request.form['release_date']
        session.delete(query)
        session.add(Movie(title,date(int(release_date.split('-')[0]),int(release_date.split('-')[1]),int(release_date.split('-')[2]))))
        session.commit()
        session.close()
        return redirect(url_for('table'))
    return render_template('edit.html',num = post_id,title = query.title,date = query.release_date)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

I have a `Movie` class defined in another script `movie.py`:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, Date, Table, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from base import Base

movies_actors_association = Table(
'movies_actors', Base.metadata,
Column('movie_id', Integer, ForeignKey('movies.id')),
Column('actor_id', Integer, ForeignKey('actors.id'))
)

class Movie(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'movies'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String)
    release_date = Column(Date)
    actors = relationship('Actor',secondary=movies_actors_association)
    def __init__(self,title,release_date):
        self.title = title
        self.release_date = release_date

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.title
```

Finally, I have 5 HTML files that I think would just clutter up the post (if it isn't already) that are just `home`, `form`, `table`, `edit`, and `base` (the one that all of them extend, containing hyperlinks to all other pages).

The library works great. I was having an `SQLAlchemy check_same_thread` issue but I've added `connect_args={'check_same_thread': False}, echo=True)` to the `engine=create_engine()` and now it runs smoothly.

I know that I should probably have several files in which I do databases, classes, page switching and such but I'm not sure about the exact structure. It also feels like I'm missing some things as some example code I've seen uses `db = SQLAlchemy(app)` but others just use the session and engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database management is kind of a mess:

- SQLAlchemy [recommend to keep your `session`s scope the same than your requests scope](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it);
- Having a single, global, `session` and closing it after a request mean that you can only ever make a single request for the whole lifetime of your application (which is not very useful);
- (I suspect that because of that) You mix using SQLAlchemy `session`s and plain `sqlite` connection, this is bad as a single tool should perform all these operations;
- You mix table creation with application operations, these should be separated into two different scripts/task: your web server operate on the table, and an administration task (either by hand or with a dedicated script) is responsible for creating them beforehand.

For simplification of these tasks, a library have been developed: [Flask-SQLAlchemy](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/)

You can have the following layout:

**movie.py**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


db = SQLAlchemy()


class Movie(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    release_date = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False)

# I’ll let you manage actors accordingly
```

**main.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash, url_for, redirect
from movie import Movie, db


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///adatabase.db'
db.init_app(app)


# regular route definitions


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And then, the table creation can simply be done by launching into your Python interpreter and doing:

```
>>> from movie import db
>>> from main import app
>>> app.app_context().push()
>>> db.create_all()
```

No need to embed this logic into your web-server. Or, at the very least, put it into a function in your `main.py`, you don't have to run this every time you launch your server.

---

Now to the part about your web server. The kind of operations you display here is know as [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete). This usually requires two kind of routes:

1. A general route to list all items of a kind and to create new ones;
2. A specific route to manage a single element (read, update, delete).

The general route usually respond to GET and POST, the specific one usually respond to GET, [PUT and DELETE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12142652/5069029).

A rough sketch of the application would be:

```
from datetime import datetime
from contextlib import suppress

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from movie import Movie, db


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///adatabase.db'
db.init_app(app)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
@app.route('/movies', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def movies():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.form['title']
        release_date = request.form['release_date']

        db.session.add(Movie(title, parse_release_date(release_date)))
        db.session.commit()

    movies = Movie.query.all()
    return render_template('movies.html', movies=movies)


@app.route('/movies/<int:post_id>', methods=['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def movie(post_id):
    the_movie = Movie.query.filter(Movie.id == post_id).first()

    if request.method == 'DELETE':
        db.session.delete(the_movie)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('movies'))

    if request.method == 'PUT':
        with suppress(KeyError):
            the_movie.title = request.form['title']
        with suppress(KeyError):
            the_movie.release_date = parse_release_date(request.form['release_date'])
        db.session.commit()

    return render_template('single_movie.html', movie=the_movie)


def parse_release_date(date):
    parsed_date = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    return parsed_date.date()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Then you just need a simple `movies.html` displaying the list of movies and providing a form to add a new one; and a `single_movie.html` presenting the informations of a movie and providing a form to update it as well as a delete button.

Answer (score 5):

## Document with docstrings.

Your functions and ORM models are currently not providing any useful documentation regarding their respective function within your program.

## Don't initialize the database on module level:

You should put that into a function:

```
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Base.metadata.bind = engine
Session = (sessionmaker(bind=engine)) #scoped_session
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session = Session()
```

## Don't do [Pokémon Exception handling](http://wiki.c2.com/?PokemonExceptionHandling).

```
try:
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.form['title']
        release_date = request.form['release_date']
        print(release_date)
        session.add(Movie(title,date(int(release_date.split('-')[0]),int(release_date.split('-')[1]),int(release_date.split('-')[2]))))
        session.commit()
        session.close()
        return redirect(url_for('table'))
except:
    flash("An error occured while writing to database")
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
return render_template('form.html', title = "Form")
```

This will catch any instance of `BaseException` and thus also `KeyboardInterrupt`s and `SytemExit`s.   Also the error message is misleading, since it would also be printed on `KeyError`s raised by `request.form['title']` or `request.form['release_date']`, which implies a user input related error, rather than an error in writing to the database.

I suggest you familiarize yourself with the *`sqlalchemy` exception APIs*<sup>1, 2</sup> and handle anticipated exceptions selectively.

---

1. http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/exceptions.html
2. http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/exceptions.html